# Fail to get the max value of a Scala List

Tags: scala

I am reading "Programming in Scala 3rd edition". When I run the example code in this book, I failed. The code is below:

```
def maxListImpParm[T](elements: List[T])
   (implicit ordering: Ordering[T]): T = {
    elements match {
        case List() => throw new IllegalArgumentException("empty list!")
        case List(x) => x
        case x :: rest => {
          val maxRest = maxListImpParm(rest)(ordering)
          if (ordering.gt(x, maxRest))  x else maxRest      }
    }
}
```

The error I got is:

```
<console>:38: error: constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : shapeless.::[H,T]
 required: List[?T1] where type ?T1 <: T (this is a GADT skolem)
     case x :: rest =>
          ^
```

The code is exact the same with the example on the book. Who can tell me what is going on here. Thanks

Comment: You almost certainly have an `import shapeless._` somewhere in your environment and `::` is shadowing `Prelude.::` - Get rid of the shapeless import so you can use the `::` object from `Prelude` instead.

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks. You are absolutely right.

Comment: I get the correct result for `maxListImpParm (List (3, 2, 4, 9, 1, 6, 8))` but the same is true for an implementation as ` = elements.max `. :)

Comment: I'd say "trivial wrong import" is very close to "trivial typo"... VtC.